# My package did not load. How can I interpret the activity log

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

My VSPackage did not load correctly into Visual Studio 2019 for one user.

The user has sent me part of the activity log:

```
<entry>
  <record>2206</record>
  <time>2019/12/13 10:44:12.579</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [MultiLanguagePackage]</description>
  <guid>{8FA8895A-868F-4319-82FD-A4805D8953CE}</guid>
</entry>

<entry>
  <record>2207</record>
  <time>2019/12/13 10:44:12.616</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>

  <description>SetSite failed for package [MultiLanguagePackage]
  Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0'; 
  Description: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
  System.NullReferenceException: 
  Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.SetPropertyValue(PropertyDescriptor descriptor, Object automationObject, Object value)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingFromStorage(PropertyDescriptor prop)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingsFromStorage()   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.set_Site(ISite value)   
  bei System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)   
  bei System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetDialogPage(Type dialogPageType)   
  bei MultiLangServices.SettingsService.InitOptionsPages(Package p) in C:\VSPackage_Version_7_1\Project\MultiLangServices\Services\SettingsService.cs:Zeile 24.   
  bei MultiLanguage2019.MultiLanguagePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()
  --- Ende der Stapel&#x00FC;berwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgel&#x00F6;st wurde ---   
  bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   
  bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass20_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()
  --- Ende der Stapel&#x00FC;berwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgel&#x00F6;st wurde ---   
  bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   
  bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UIThreadReentrancyScope.WaitOnTaskCompleteInternal(Task task, CancellationToken cancel, Int32 ms)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass100_1.&lt;InternalGetResult&gt;b__1()   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.IgnoreObjectDisposedException(Action action)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass100_0.&lt;InternalGetResult&gt;b__0()   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass108_0.&lt;InvokeWithWaitDialog&gt;b__0()   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog[T](Func`1 function)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InvokeWithWaitDialog(Action action)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)   
  bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>

  <guid>{8FA8895A-868F-4319-82FD-A4805D8953CE}</guid>
  <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
  <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>

<entry>
  <record>2208</record>
  <time>2019/12/13 10:44:12.618</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [MultiLanguagePackage]</description>
  <guid>{8FA8895A-868F-4319-82FD-A4805D8953CE}</guid>
  <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
  <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

How can I interpret this information?
Does it contain any useful pointer to the cause of the error?

My package contains a reference to the NuGet package Micorosft.VisualStudio.SDK version 16.0.202.

It does not contain a specific reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `MultiLanguageService` class belongs to your package implementation - it is doing something that causes a `NullReferenceException`. Such error should be easy to locate; the stack trace tells you that something is going wrong in  `MultiLangServices.SettingsService.InitOptionsPages(Package p) in ...SettingsService.cs:Zeile 24`. Just put a breakpoint to line 24 and verify if everything behaves as expected.

I don´t think that it is related to a certain SDK-package or -assembly that you´ve referenced. If the code works for the majority of the users, there must be something in the code that may fail under certain circumstances; for instance, a configuration value that results in the reported `NullReferenceException` exception, if missing. I would inspect the implementation and at least add a proper exception handler so that, next time, a more precise error will be reported to the activity-log.

Comment: Thanks. I was fairly blind not to spot that. I can certainly add an exception handler.